# Target button element to be static when resizing window in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a navbar with a few elements inside it and a button that escapes the navbar when i resize it. What CSS property should I style to keep the button in CSS to stop the button from escaping the navbar?

Attached is a JFiddle of an example of what happens:

https://jsfiddle.net/6Lx0hkfa/

```css
.green-button {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 235px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background-color: rgb(185, 233, 137);
  color: rgb(43, 150, 190);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: initial;
  border-color: initial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="address">7542 Fay Ave Upstairs Suite, La Jolla, CA 92037</div>
    <div class="phone">(858) 381-0740</div>
    <div class="email">sdacneclinic@gmail.com</div>
    <div class="social">
      <a class="social-btn fb" href="http://facebook.com"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
      <a class="social-btn tw" href="http://twitter.com"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
      <a class="social-btn ig" href="http://instagram.com"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
      <a class="social-btn gp" href="https://plus.google.com"></a>
    </div>
    <a href="/contacts">
      <button class="green-button">Book Consultation</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but this one worked for me:

```
.green-button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where I would use `float` for simplicity. Note that this requires to put the link element on top of the rest of the wrapper's contents within the markup, but it's the most direct solution.

```css
.green-button-link {
  float: left;
}
.green-button {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 170px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background-color: rgb(185, 233, 137);
  color: rgb(43, 150, 190);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: initial;
  border-color: initial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="green-button-link" href="/contacts">
      <button class="green-button">Book Consultation</button>
    </a>
    <div class="address">7542 Fay Ave Upstairs Suite, La Jolla, CA 92037</div>
    <div class="phone">(858) 381-0740</div>
    <div class="email">sdacneclinic@gmail.com</div>
    <div class="social">
      <a class="social-btn fb" href="http://facebook.com"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
      <a class="social-btn tw" href="http://twitter.com"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
      <a class="social-btn ig" href="http://instagram.com"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
      <a class="social-btn gp" href="https://plus.google.com"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the snippet if its what you want.i added description `add` to ones I added to your code.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 background: url(img/hero_bg.jpg) repeat-y center center fixed;
 background size: 100%;
}

#header {
 background-color: #1d7cb6;
 display: block;
 /* position: relative; */
 color: white;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0px auto;
 font-family: 'Raleway';
 background: white;
 z-index: 500;
 vertical-align: middle;/* add */
 position: relative;/* add */
 padding-right: 200px;
}

.address {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 240px;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 10px;
 padding: 20px 18px;
}

.phone {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 10px;
 padding: 20px 18px;
}

.email {
 width: 150px;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 20px 18px;
 font-size: 10px;
}

a.social-btn {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 margin-top: 13px;
 float: left;
 
}

a.social-btn.fb {
 background: url("img/facebook@2x.png") 0% 0%/ 20px 20px no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}

a.social-btn.tw {
 background: url("img/twitter@2x.png") 0% 0% / 20px 20px no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}

a.social-btn.ig {
 background: url("img/instagram@2x.png") 0% 0% / 20px 20px no-repeat;
}

a.social-btn.gp {
 background: url("img/google@2x.png") 0% 0% / 20px 20px no-repeat;
}

section {
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

section#header .wrapper button.green-button {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Raleway';
}

.green-button {
 font-size: 13px;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 50px;
 width: 170px;
/*  float: left; */
 right: 0;/* add */
 position: absolute;/* add */
/*  margin-left: 235px; */
 padding: 6px 10px;
 background-color: rgb(185, 233, 137);
 color: rgb(43, 150, 190);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-radius: 0px;
 border-width: 0px;
 border-style: initial;
 border-color: initial;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="address">7542 Fay Ave Upstairs Suite, La Jolla, CA 92037</div>
        <div class="phone">(858) 381-0740</div>
        <div class="email">sdacneclinic@gmail.com</div>
        <div class="social"><a class="social-btn fb" href="http://facebook.com"></a></div>
        <div class="social"><a class="social-btn tw" href="http://twitter.com"></a></div>
        <div class="social"><a class="social-btn ig" href="http://instagram.com"></a></div>
        <div class="social"><a class="social-btn gp" href="https://plus.google.com"></a></div>
        <a href="/contacts"><button class="green-button">Book Consultation</button></a>
    </div>
</section>
```